# Email undilivered to one of the receivers. will anyone get the mail?

Tags: gmail

I sent a mail a few hours ago( suppose to person A and person B) but one of them lets say person A has a system in place such that mails from unknown Id's are blocked but person B doesn't, so person A did not receive the mail and I got a not delivered response back from the email bot.
My question is if email to person A was blocked, will person B receive the mail or not (Person B does not have the said security in place and can receive my mails)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found out that everyone except the one for whom it was undelivered will get the mail.

Comment: That would make sense logically.  Delivery isn't instantaneous, so person B could have already received and read the message long before the delivery to A failed. Delivery could also be to two completely different mail servers, and there isn't any mechanism for A's server to communicate with B's server, even if it wanted to.